# getDoctrine() not working in FOSUserBundle symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I need to create a drop-down of states such that as soon as i select country from country drop_down then states drop_down of that country should come up using Ajax. 
I am getting error following error.

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine" of class "FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController"

The AJAX is getting called and the id of the country is being passed to the controller , the main problem is the `getDoctrine` function.
Here is my controller.

I am new to symfony , please help me.

```
public function getStateAction(Request $request)
    {               
            $em1 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $data = $request->request->all();   

            $countryId = $data['id'];
            $repository = $em->getRepository('FOSUserBundle:State');
            $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');
            $query->where('p.country ='.$countryId);
            $query->orderBy('p.id', 'ASC');
            $stateList = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
            //print_r($stateList); die;
    }
```

Here is my ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#fos_user_registration_form_country_id").change(function(){
    var countryId = $(this).val();
             if(countryId!=0){
               $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "{{ path('fos_user_registration_country') }}",
               data: {id: countryId},
               cache: false,
               success: function(result){
               ("#fos_user_registration_form_state_id").append(result);
             }
           });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please correct your syntax and structure your text in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with:

```
public function getStateAction(Request $request)
{   
    $em1 = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();

    /.../
}
```

`getDoctrine()` is a method of the class `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` who is not extended from `FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController`

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using a version of FOSUserBundle that isn't the latest master version. Your issue is due to the fact that, up until the dev-master version, the `RegistrationController` extended `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware` rather than `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`. The `Controller` class extends `ContainerAware` and contains a bunch of shortcut calls like `getDoctrine`, `generateUrl` and `isGranted`.

The `getDoctrine` method just calls the container like..

```
/**
 * Shortcut to return the Doctrine Registry service.
 *
 * @return Registry
 *
 * @throws \LogicException If DoctrineBundle is not available
 */
protected function getDoctrine()
{
    if (!$this->container->has('doctrine')) {
        throw new \LogicException('The DoctrineBundle is not registered in your application.');
    }

    return $this->container->get('doctrine');
}
```

You have 2 options: copy the `getDoctrine` method into your class, or just use `$this->container->get('doctrine')` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I added this line to my controller and the controller was inheriting from container instead of controller. Thankyou for the help @scoolnico.

```
 public function getStateAction(Request $request)
        {               
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                /../


        }
```